# enable modules in drupal multisite install

Tags: drupal

I have a multisite drupal instalation. I have one module used in a specific site in sites/site2/moduleSpecific.

I just can see modules in sites/all in the backend and not the one I put in the folder site2!

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the module under sites/site2/modules/moduleName

Comment: okay. Dis so. tx. But in the backend i am not seeing the module in the backend